# Qt - How to change a QTextEdit's font size with a QComboBox

Tags: c++, qt, qcombobox, qtextedit

im trying to change the font size of a QTextEdit by using a QComboBox which is filled in with different values, so for example when I choose a value in the QComboBox it will change the QTextEdits size to the value I have selected. I have values in the QComboBox but I don't know how to change the QTextEdit's value to the value I have selected.

Below is the code I used to fill the QComboBox with values:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 102; i+=2){
  QStringList list = (QStringList()<<QString::number(i));
  ui->combobox->addItem(list);
```

Any help on what to do from here would be appreciated thank you!

Comment: Why don't you use a `QSpinBox` ? It would be much better for the task

Comment: Not sure how to use it, but i used it because word uses (what looks like) a combo box and therefore using a combo box would just be something everyone is used. however im happy to have suggestions, many thanks.

Comment: [HERE](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qspinbox.html#details) you have the description and some images of what it looks like

Comment: Thank you for the response, and actual this is a good idea, however i have implemented the combobox now, and prefer it. Thank you though.

Comment: the good thing of `QSpinbox`is that you can do directly the connection: `connect(fontSizeSpin, SIGNAL(valueChanged(int), textEdit, SLOT(setFontPointSize(int));`  without having to write the slot `changeFontSize` as @ramtheconqueror suggest in an answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
QTextEdit* textEdit = new QTextEdit(......);

QComboBox* fontSizeCombo = new QComboBox(....);
for (int i = 1; i < 102; i += 2) {
  fontSizeCombo->addItem(QString::number(i));
}
connect(fontSizeCombo, SIGNAL(currentIndexChanged(QString), SLOT(changeFontSize(QString));

void MyClass::changeFontSize(const QString& selected)
{
  textEdit->setFontPointSize(selected.toInt());
}
```

Don't need appending `QStringList` with each item.

Don't set font size to 0. Excerpt from the Qt docs:

> Note that if s is zero or negative, the behavior of this function is
>   not defined.